# Access js object using variable

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if I'm correct with topic title, so sorry about that.
I've got JS object '_buildings', which structure looks like this:

```
_buildings : {
        laboratory : {
            exist : false,
            value : 1000,
        },
        office : {
            exist : false,
            value : 500,
        },
}
```

Is it possible to access object somehow using this method:

```
var chain = 'laboratory'; //it could be 'office' or any other building name
var value = _buildings.chain.value;
```

Point is, I need to access object param while using variable in chain. Is it possible?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3k5anjjj/

Comment: do you know that objects in JavaScript are really just key-pairs and that you `can[subscript]` them with any expression?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Having answered this myself ive also voted to close as there is at least one duplicate on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, use square bracket notation

```
var x = _buildings[chain].value;
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3k5anjjj/1/

Comment: Thank you, I will approve your answer after timeout.